# A question about positive definite and symmetric matrices

Tags: positive-definite

Suppose $A$, $B$ are real $n \times n$ matrices, and $A$, $AB$ are symmetric with $A$ positive definite. Is the matrix $B$ diagonalizable and having real eigenvalues ?

Could someone give me a hint about this question ?